# How to check if value type is Dictionary<String, Any>

Tags: swift

I created a function in Swift that loop through a dynamic dictionary, however when I try to check if the value is a Dictionary type the type comparison condition always fails, in fact XCode raises the following warning as hint:

```
Cast from '(key: String, value: Any)' to unrelated type 'Dictionary<String, Any>' always fails.
```

I am not trying to cast any value, I just want to check if the variable value has the type Dictionary.

This is my code:

```
    func readNode(node: Dictionary<String, Any>, level: Int)
    {

        // Print spaces
        for _ in 0 ... level
        {
            print(" ")
        }


        for (key, val) in node.enumerated()
        {

            // The following condition is always false (here is the issue)                
            if val is Dictionary<String, Any> {
                print("Key \(key):")
                readNode(node: val, level: (level + 1) * 2)
            }
            else
            {
                print("Key \(key): \(val)")
            }

        }

    }

    var mydict = Dictionary<String, Any>()

    mydict = ["subindex2": 2, "subindex3": 3, "subindex4": ["whatever": "extra"]]

    readNode(node: mydict, level: 0)
```

I am using Swift 3.0.1.

Comment: Why are you using enumerated on the `node` parameter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`enumerated()` creates a sequence of consecutive `Int`s starting from 0, paired with the elements of the sequence you call it on. That's not what you want – you just want to iterate over a given dictionary's key-value pairs. So just remove `.enumerated()`, and iterate over the dictionary directly.

You'll also want to employ conditional type-casting rather than a simple `is` check, allowing `val` to be statically typed as `[String : Any]` in the success branch (otherwise you won't be able to pass it back into `readNode(node:level:)`).

```
// ...

for (key, val) in node {
    if let val = val as? [String : Any] {
        print("Key \(key):")
        readNode(node: val, level: (level + 1) * 2)
    } else {
        print("Key \(key): \(val)")
    }
}

// ...
```

Comment: Thanks Hamish, so the issue was with the .enumerated. I wrote this code as exercise in order to learn Swift. I didn't know that I can access to the dictionary index without the enumerated method. It is a little bit confused because the Apple manual say: "If you need the integer index of each item as well as its value, use the enumerated() method to iterate over the array instead. For each item in the array, the enumerated()". I know that a Dictionary is not an array, however I observed that this method was also present for Dictionary type.

Comment: @JuanLago It's a misconception about `enumerated()` that it deals with the indices of a collection – it only deals with a simple `Int` counter from 0. In the case of `Array`, this just *happens* to align nicely with the indices, but this is very rarely the case with other collections. `Dictionary` has an `Element` type of `(Key, Value)` anyway (allowing you to access both keys and values when iterating). This combined with the fact that you can subscript it with a `Key` means that you rarely need to use its actual `Index` type (which is completely unrelated to its `Key` btw).

Comment: Thanks again with the explanation. It seems that I have to study Swift more in deep in order to know better this small details. Can you recommend me some book about Swift?

Comment: @JuanLago I'm afraid I don't have any book recommendations, but for the most part, the language guide is really good to learn from.

Comment: I would however always recommend looking up methods like [`enumerated()` in the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/sequence/1641222-enumerated) (which is also quite good for the most part). In this case, there's a helpful paragraph saying "*When enumerating a collection, the integer part of each pair is a counter for the enumeration, not necessarily the index of the paired value. These counters can only be used as indices in instances of zero-based, integer-indexed collections, such as Array and ContiguousArray.*"